# wp_redirect is only working in Chrome Network, page is not redirecting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I created a custom WordPress Payment Plugin for WooCommerce, Everything is working fine. When I try to use `wp_redirect('url');` page starts to load in Browser Network, but the page is not redirecting it gives me the following error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (!wp_doing_ajax()) {
          $url = 'https://www.example.com';
          wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
```

Wrap your redirect if not doing an ajax request.